# android.app.AlertDialog custom themes not working

Tags: android, themes, android-alertdialog, android-theme, android-styles

I want to change default AlertDialog theme.

None of the examples I found worked. Here is what I'm doing:

```
<style name="LightTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/MyCustomDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Add you layout (`xml`) or class code where you are using this theme.

Comment: Shouldn't this change the theme for whole project? I'm using `new AlertDialog.Builder(context)`

Comment: Is your `LightTheme` main app theme (which you are using e.g. in Manifest)?

Comment: Yes, it is. `android:theme="@style/LightTheme"`

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have a solution.

You have to replace `android.app.AlertDialog` by `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` and in your custom theme you **must** set `<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>`